# Regular expression and removing signs

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new in regular expressions. I've got a little problem and i can't find the answer. I'm looking for redundant brackets using this regular espression:

```
public Regex RedundantBrackets = new Regex("[(](\\s?)[a-z](\\s?)[)]");
```

When i find something i want to modife string in this way:

`text1 (text2) text3 => text1 text2 text3`  - so as you can se i want only to remove brackets. How can i do this? I was trying to use Replace method, but using it i can only replace every sign of `"(text2)"`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your regular expression only allows a single letter inside the parentheses. You need `[a-z]*?` to match a sequence of letters.

Comment: Are all parantheses redundant, or are there some which are not?

Comment: This is not related to regex, but a bracket is [ and ] and a parenthesis is either ( or ) and a curly brace is { or }.

Comment: In this example there should be only one letter inside patentheses. All patentheses are redundant (of course if there is "(" and ")" and this is why i'm checking that in this way).

Comment: It's not clear what "redundant" means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replace

```
Regex.Replace("text1 (text2) text3", // Input
              @"([()])",             // Pattern to match
              string.Empty)          // Item to replace

/* result: text1 text2 text3*/
```

#### Explanation

Regex replace looks across the whole string for a match. If it finds a match it will replace that item. So our match pattern looks like this `([()])`. Which means this

1. `(` is what is required within the pattern to start the match and needs a closing `)` otherwise the match pattern is not balanced.
2. `[]` in the pattern says, I am searching for a character, and `[` and `]` define a set. They are considered set matches. The most common one is [A-Z] which is any set of characters, starting with A and ending in Z. We will define our own set. *Remember [ and ] mean to regex we are looking for **1** character but we specify a set of many characters within that.
3. `(` and `)` within our set `[()]` *which also could be specified as `[)(]` as well* means we have a set of two characters. Those two characters are the opening and closing parenthesis `()`.

So taken all together we are looking to match (1) any character in the set (2) that is either a ( or a ). When that match is found, replace the ( or ) with string.empty.

When we run the regex replace on your text it finds two matches the `(`text2 and finally the match text2`)`. Those are replaced with string.empty.

Comment: @user2229474 Maybe you should read a tutorial on regex. This is a very basic regex that you should know about.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it can be handy to use verbatim strings so you don't have to escape the slashes etc.

```
public Regex RedundantBrackets = new Regex(@"[(]\s?([a-z]+)\s?[)]");
```

We want to wrap `[a-z]` in parenthesis because that's what we're trying to capture. We can then use `$1` to place that capture into the replacement

```
RedundantBrackets.Replace("text (text) text", "$1");
```

EDIT: I forgot to add repetition to `[a-z]` => `[a-z]+`

Answer (score 0):

this will remove all charaters using regex

finalString = Regex.Replace(finalString, @"[^\w ]", "");